# Resetting staggering animation delay on newly generated elements

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to implement a stagger animation when my page is loaded by getting an array of users from my API, then assigning this array to a local variable which is bound to a table with ngFor which then loops and displays the values.

I am currently using scss to create an animation delay variable which loops a finite number of times. The initial elements load and stagger just fine but when a new element is added to the array variable, it keeps the last used stagger delay value which causes it to appear much later into the view.

I have tried using Angulars built in stagger function with animations but it does not seem to work. I have seen some github reports which say that its an issue with query. I can create a basic animation which works fine but when using stagger inside of query then the animations just dont fire.
Here is the link to said github report:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19786

Here is my scss file

```css
.userrow{
  animation: .3s ease-in-out both fade-in-entry;
  //animation-delay: .5s;
}



@keyframes fade-in-entry{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(+100%);
  }

  100%{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

}

@for $i from 1 through 21 {
  .userrow:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: #{$i * 0.2}s;
  }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<tr style = "background: lightblue;" >
  <th>UserID</th>
  <th>UserName</th>
  <th>FirstName</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
</tr>

<tr *ngFor='let user of _userService.users' class="userrow">

  <td>{{user.userID}}</td>
  <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
  <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
  <td><button (click)="deleteUser(user.userID)">Delete</button></td>


</tr>
```

I have a separate form component which takes a user name and first name and posts a new user object to the database. It is then provided with a JSON which includes the newly created User as well as a generated ID number. I then push this user to the local array and it is added to the table. I would like when the user is added to the array, it still maintains animation but appears as soon as its added to the array, and not with a long delay because its using the previous delay variable.

Furthermore, I would also like to have a way to delete these elements from the view when the user clicks delete, and then have the table reflect the change without refreshing the whole table and triggering all the rows animations again.